# Como resolver esta consulta de SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Listar nombre y teléfono de los chóferes que no manejaron algún vehículo de
modelo posterior al año 2010.**

*LO QUE INTENTE YO*

```
SELECT c.nombre, c.telefono
FROM chofer as c 
INNER JOIN viaje as v on c.nro_chofer = v.nro_chofer
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM auto
WHERE modelo > 2010);
```

MI BASE DE DATOS:

```
create table auto
(
patente varchar(50),
modelo varchar(50),
año int,
primary key (patente)
);

create table chofer
(
nombre varchar(50),
telefono int,
nro_chofer int,
fecha_ingreso varchar(50),
primary key (nro_chofer)
);

create table cliente
(
nombre varchar(50),
domicilio varchar(50),
nro_cliente int,
localidad varchar(50),
primary key (nro_cliente)
);

create table viaje
(
patente varchar(50),
nro_chofer int,
nro_cliente int,
fecha varchar(50),
km_totales int,
tiempo_espera varchar(50),
primary key (nro_cliente, nro_chofer, patente, fecha),
foreign key (nro_cliente) references cliente (nro_cliente),
foreign key (nro_chofer) references chofer (nro_chofer),
foreign key (patente) references auto (patente)
);
```

Comment: Una pregunta, el modelo está declarado como `VARCHAR` ... `modelo varchar(50)` ¿no deberías comparar con el `año` en ese caso?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer `LEFT JOIN`, en la tabla `auto` agregas además la condición `modelo > 2010`, filtras con `NOT NULL` y agrupas por `nro_chofer`:

```
SELECT 
    ch.nombre,
    ch.telefono
FROM viajes v 
   LEFT JOIN  chofer ch ON v.nro_chofer = ch.nro_chofer 
   LEFT JOIN  auto   a  ON v.patente    = a.patente AND a.modelo > 2010
WHERE a.patente IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  ch.nro_chofer;
```